# Section Numbering in "Convex Optimizaion" by Boyd et. al. with Koma Script

Tags: sectioning, koma-script

I like the way the section numbering is typeset in the book [Convex Optimization](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/), i.e. the sections numbers are placed in the margin.[image]

How do I achieve this style with the `scrbook` class from the `KOMA-script` package?

**Partial Solution:** This [code snippet](http://www.howtotex.com/tips-tricks/section-numbering-in-margins/) seems to do the trick, but, as cgnieder points out in the comment section below, the numbers are not centered relative to each other.

Comment: Could you explain yourself better and add an Minimal Working Example (MWE) for see what you need. We don't know if you're working with the `scrartcl` class o another.

Comment: On the first glance, there is nothing special about this, except from (apparently?) centered section number over the subsection number.  By the way: `amsbook` class and `KOMA` are very different classes/packages.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Notice that the section numbers are placed in the margin.

Comment: @ChristopherMorris: It could be the margin, it could be that the content is indented ... it's hard to say from this screen shot

Comment: @ChristianHupfer but the latter would seem rather strange to me. Besides: if it is the latter then effectively the margin is bigger and the numbers still are in the margin :)

Comment: @cgnieder: That depends on the opinion, what belongs to the margin ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Good point, have a look at http://stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf.

At least on pages with an odd page number the section numbers seem to be placed in the margin.

Comment: I added a solution.

Comment: @ChristopherMorris with the solution of the link you added the numbers will be placed in the margin. In the picture in your post they're also *centered* relative to each other which the linked solution doesn't have.

Comment: @cgnieder: Good point, I would prefer the later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a modified version of the linked solution. In the linked solution you have

```
\renewcommand*\othersectionlevelsformat[1]{%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{%
    \csname the#1\endcsname
    \enskip
  }%
}
```

This puts the sectioning number in a box of zero width aligned to the right which is why the number sticks into the margin. The `\enskip` ensures a distance of 1en between number and heading. It is flawed, though. As the KOMA-Script manual describes `\othersectionlevelsformat` has *three* arguments and the 3rd is the corresponding `\the<counter`. A better definition would be

```
\renewcommand*\othersectionlevelsformat[3]{%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{#3\enskip}%
}
```

Now that the definition is corrected we can adjust it. In order to have the numbers horizontally centered to each other you could put a second box into the first with a certain given width (1.5cm, say) and have the contents centered:

```
\renewcommand*\othersectionlevelsformat[3]{%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[1.5cm][c]{#3\autodot}}%
}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\renewcommand*\othersectionlevelsformat[3]{%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[1.5cm][c]{#3\autodot}}%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Adjusting this to `scrbook` and chapters is easy: we just need a corresponding definition for `\chapterformat`. This command has *no* arguments and we use `\thechapter` for placing the number.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\newcommand*\marginnumber[1]{\makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[1.5cm][c]{#1}}}
\renewcommand*\chapterformat{\marginnumber{\thechapter\autodot}}
\renewcommand*\othersectionlevelsformat[3]{\marginnumber{#3\autodot}}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to extend your solution to chapter headings?

Comment: Sure. I'll add something tomorrow. (It's late on my side of the world :))

Comment: @ChristopherMorris I added something and discovered that the definition from the blog post is flawed. Maybe you should tell the author

Comment: One more question, is it possible to adapt the above code such that the chapter number is in the margin and the chapter title is centered?

Comment: @ChristopherMorris probably. But I'd have to investigate how as well. Probably best if you ask a new question...

Comment: I asked a new question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197516/place-chapter-numbers-in-the-margin-and-center-chapter-titles.