# Place chapter numbers in the margin and center chapter titles

Tags: koma-script, scrbook

This is follow up question from [Section Numbering in "Convex Optimizaion" by Boyd et. al. with Koma Script](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196963/section-numbering-in-convex-optimizaion-by-boyd-et-al-with-koma-script/196981?noredirect=1#comment458008_196981).

Is it possible, using the `scrbook` class, to place the chapter (section) numbers in the margin and center the chapter (section) titles?

Comment: Anything is possible, but some things are easier than others.  Basically, this will invole replacing the given \chapter command.

Comment: Are you simply looking for `\renewcommand\raggedsection\centering`?

Comment: @Johannes_B   No, the chapter numbers should be placed in the margin, cf. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196963/section-numbering-in-convex-optimizaion-by-boyd-et-al-with-koma-script/196981?noredirect=1#comment458008_196981.

Comment: You have to add my line to the other answer.

Comment: @Johannes_B No, that does not work, because the chapter numbers well be centered, too.

Note: when using ``koma-script``you should write ``\addtokomafont{disposition}{\centering}``.

Comment: Oh, you are right. I was too careless, sorry.

Comment: Looking at the source for scrbook (Aaaaagh!) I noticed that the table of contents uses \chapter to write "Contents" so if you change the chapter format you will also change the table of contents format.

Comment: Yes, that's perfectly fine with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version implements requests and advice from comments.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}%
  \llap{\thechapter\autodot\enskip%
}}
\renewcommand*{\@@makechapterhead}[1]{\chapterheadstartvskip
  {%
    \normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\size@chapter{}%
    \noindent\ifnumbered{chapter}{\chapterformat}\fi
    \parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\centering\size@chapter{#1}}%
  \nobreak\chapterheadendvskip\par
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Center}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to place the chapter numbers in the left margin centered relative as in cgnieder's solution for http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196963/section-numbering-in-convex-optimizaion-by-boyd-et-al-with-koma-script/196981?noredirect=1#comment458008_196981?

Comment: Sure.  I assume you would want it right justified, since the left margin is smaller (odd page).

Comment: Sorry, it took longer than expected.

Comment: You're missing a `%` after `{\nobreakspace}`; moreover `\size@chapter` has no argument. Instead of a group with a setting of `\parindent`, just `\noindent\mbox` is sufficient.

Comment: @egreg - Thanks.  I tend to leave the original code unchanged if I'm not sure what it does.